# New user Registration data imported into Page

Tags: pages, users

Here's my goal....New users apply to use a site that I'm working on.  When I get an application, I talk to them, and afterwards I approve them.  From there, the information they supplied online is automatically imported into a page.  The page can be edited by the user or any admin.  The user can only edit their own page.

Here's what I've done so far...I'm using Register Plus Redux to gather all of the additional information from the user that I need while they are registering for the site. This is done through the usual wp-login.php?action=register  This works well. The user is 'unverified' when they initially apply online.  I get the form, talk to them, and then I can approve them online.  Everything works well in this area.  From there I don't know how to get all of that information transferred over to the user's page. When I say page, I mean an actual 'Page' not their user account page. If you know of a good way without manually copying and pasting let me know.  I'm then using Capability Manager Enhanced to stop the user from deleting or editing other pages.  The only thing I also need in this area, is to allow the user to only have 1 page total.

I know this is a lot so any help with any part of it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!